# If I receive dopamine only from doing difficult things will I eventually enjoy them?

Tags: brain, neurotransmitter, dopamine

I've recently read a post from reddit about how dopamine affects our motivation. Author states:

> Dopamine is pleasure. Your brain craves more pleasure. You get too
> much pleasure and your brain adapts to feel like tons of pleasure is
> less pleasure then everything else becomes more boring. Cut those big
> pleasure spikes out and everything else becomes more pleasurable. Your
> dopamine receptors change to interact with less dopamine when you have
> too much and when you cut down on dopamine, your dopamine receptors
> change to interact with more dopamine. This makes boring stuff fun. Do
> boring things long enough and endure until it becomes pleasurable via
> dopamine receptors. And remember, think in terms of dopamine the next
> time you feel like not doing what you need to do!

He advises to stop listening music, playing video games, watching porn, digital entertainment intake. He says:

> This will make your dopamine receptors less dull over time and more receptive to lower levels of dopamine so doing things that are boring now will eventually feel not-boring if you can cut out big dopamine spikes.
>
> Then, you keep doing the things you know you need to do but don't feel like doing long enough until your dopamine receptors become used to less dopamine and those things will feel good to do.

Some people accused author because of bro-science in his post. Can someone prove the theory or debunk it?

**Will I enjoy doing difficult things which don't give me pleasure now if it's my only dopamine source?**

Comment: Reddit is not always a reliable source. Have you done any research into this? What have you found?

Comment: Perhaps it's just a language issue, but 'difficult' and 'boring' are vastly different.  Backcountry skiing, flying your plane into short mountain strips, or playing a musical instrument can be difficult, but not boring - at least to me.  OTOH, video games, porn, and digital entertainment are boring to me.  And though I've scrubbed my toilet regularly for all my adult life, it's never become pleasurable.  So it seems that there's a major flaw in the argument :-)

Comment: I recall times when I found anything boring except activities which author advises to give up. Since the moment I quit playing video games I became interested in many things which previously seemed to me very boring and uninteresting.
 
For clarification, by difficult things I mean things you [have to]/[need to]/[should to] do but they seem boring and uninteresting and you don't enjoy them. Interesting things can be challenging, but if I enjoy them they aren't difficult to me. So difficult - hard to bear.